# MOQ problem - mocked class returns incorrect data

Tags: nunit, moq, testing, repository-pattern

So, I'm using moq for testing, but I ran into a problem that prevents me from mocking correctly, at least I think so.
This is my repository class:

```
public interface IAccountsRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Account> Accounts { get; }
        IQueryable<Account> AccountsPaged(int pageSize, int selectedPage);
    }
```

This is one of the implementations (fake):

```
public class FakeAccountsRepository : IAccountsRepository
    {
        private static readonly IQueryable<Account> FakeAccounts = new List<Account> {
        new Account {RegistrationEmail = "first@demo.org"},
        new Account {RegistrationEmail = "second@demo.org"},
        new Account {RegistrationEmail = "third@demo.org"},
        new Account {RegistrationEmail = "fourth@demo.org"},
        new Account {RegistrationEmail = "fifth@demo.org"}
        }.AsQueryable();

        public IQueryable<Account> Accounts
        {
            get { return FakeAccounts; }
        }

        public IQueryable<Account> AccountsPaged(int pageSize, int selectedPage)
        {
            return FakeAccounts.Skip((selectedPage - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

This is a Controller definition that works perfectly with real page and fake or sql data (IoC) inside a real web page:

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        private IAccountsRepository _accountsRepository;
        public int PageSize = 3;

        public AccountsController(IAccountsRepository accountsRepository)
        {
            this._accountsRepository = accountsRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List(int selectedPage)
        {
               return View(_accountsRepository.AccountsPaged(PageSize, selectedPage).ToList());
        }
    }
```

This is a moq method:

```
static IAccountsRepository MockAccountsRepository(params Account[] accs)
        {
            // Generate an implementor of IAccountsRepository at runtime using Moq
            var mockProductsRepos = new Moq.Mock<IAccountsRepository>();
            mockProductsRepos.Setup(x => x.Accounts).Returns(accs.AsQueryable());
            return mockProductsRepos.Object;
        }
```

it works fine with this implementation of List pagination:

```
public ViewResult List(int selectedPage)
        {
            return View(_accountsRepository.Accounts.Skip((selectedPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList());

        }
```

but it fails when using this:

```
public ViewResult List(int selectedPage)
        {
            return View(_accountsRepository.AccountsPaged(PageSize, selectedPage).ToList());
        }
```

Without changing test and changing only List implementation (doing pagination only on .Accounts) it all works, but when I try to use AccountsPaged method, it Fails returning no elements.
In real usage, on a web page, it works both ways.

Please advise, thank you.

EDIT:
If I do this:

```
mockProductsRepos.Setup(x => x.AccountsPaged(Moq.It.IsAny<int>(), Moq.It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(accs.AsQueryable());
```

I get 5 items returned instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't setup AccountsPaged method in your mock

EDIT: Now that you setup AccountsPaged, you didn't setup it properly. Here how to setup it properly:

```
mockProductsRepos
   .Setup(x => x.AccountsPaged(Moq.It.IsAny<int>(), Moq.It.IsAny<int>()))
   .Returns( (int pageSize, int selectedPage) => accs.Skip((selectedPage-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable() );
```

Comment: I did setup it now, like I've added to the post above, but it gives me 5 items instead of 2 - which would be expected if .List() call worked correctly. I don't know how could it be and why does it return full members? Is there a way to step by step debug of the moq setup?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't parse through your code in any depth, but a general rule of thumb is - When in doubt regarding mock correctness, use strict mocking to flush out any missing expectations:

var mock = new Mock(MockBehavior.Strict);

that way you will get explicit indications of any unexpected calls issued by the SUT which you forgot to mock.